# BizTalk BAM portal "unauthorized"

Tags: iis, biztalk, biztalk-bam, biztalk-2016

I have installed and configured BizTalk and followed the Warehouse tutorial.  I am now trying to use the BAM portal as BizTalk seems to be processing my documents, but they are just disappearing into the ether rather than arriving at either of my destination end points.

The error I am getting is "HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers."

I have tried all of the authentication methods, given "Everyone" read/write/execute privilege on the portal directory (this is just a stand alone vm on my pc!) but I can't get past this problem.  I am not an IIS expert, so this is probably a simple fix, but I am darned if I can see what it is.

Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2016, IIS Version 10.0.14393, BizTalk Server Version 3.12.774.0 (BizTalk 2016)

**EDIT**
I enabled Anonymous Authentication and disabled ASP.NET Impersonation.  This changed the error to "Access is denied".  This would tend to indicate that the application is happy with Anonymous Authentication, but something is wrong with the permissions on the actual folder.  I have again checked, including the two sub-sites and everyone has all permissions on all the folders (I know this is overkill, but I am just trying to get this working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a very simple fix in the end.  Windows Authentication was not available as an option, so I installed this and now I can get to the page.